# Javascript dynamic parameters, and saving query result to it

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, dynamic, parameters

I'm kinda new to javascript and node and I'm having a hard time on this one. I've tried with solutions suggested at questions about creating objects dynamically but now the problem is saving the query into it.

So in general terms I've a Restaurant, that has a Menu, which has categories, that has products. Therefore, I recieve a Restaurant_id, to find it's menu, then it's categories and finally the products in each category. I start at the 2nd query cause i figured everything else already.

```
connection.query("SELECT id_section, name FROM menu_section WHERE id_menu = ?", [id_menu], function(err, results) {

      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("Result 2nd query " + JSON.stringify(results));
      //^^ this logs: Result 2nd query [{"id_section":1,"name":"Beverages"},{"id_section":2,"name":"Breakfast"}]

      var size = results.length;
      var id_section = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        result_menu[results[i].name] = ""; //this creates the object named result_menu with first parameter Beverages and 2nd breakfast
        params[i] = results[i].name;
        console.log("Inserted dynamic params: " + params[i]); // this logs Beverages, and Breakfast
        id_section[i] = results[i].id_section; //this saves the ID of each sections in that menu so I know what to query next
        console.log("Inserted ID's" + id_section[i]); //this logs 1 and 2, which are my section ID's

          connection.query("SELECT name, price FROM menu_product WHERE id_section = ? AND active = 1", 
          [id_section[i]], function(err, results2) {
            console.log(results2); //this log shows me that my query is right in both cycles: [ RowDataPacket { name: 'Heineken', price: 40 } ]
            result_menu[params[i]] = results2; // trying to insert first query on params[i] which contains "Beverages" and "Breakfast" 
            console.log("value of : " + JSON.stringify(result_menu));
            //last log, logs: "value of : {"Beverages":"","Breakfast":"","undefined":[{"name":"Heineken","price":40}]}"    
          });

      }  
      connection.release();
      callback(result_menu); 
    });
```

Sorry for the long code, but it seems necessary. Problem is... I've created parameters Dynamically already, but Postman gives me the next result and also the created "undefined" parameter shown in the logs doesn't even show in callback:

```
{
  "Beverages": "",
  "Breakfast": ""
}
```

And what I actually wanna built is something like:

```
{
  "Beverages": [{"name": "Heineken", "price": "45"}, {"name": "Coke", "price": "10"}],
  "Breakfast": [{"name": "Eggs", "price": "65"}, {"name": "Pancakes", "price": "70"}]
}
```

I have no idea, why js is not saving the query results... how am I supposed to do it? Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a general point, why not store this 'view' of the data as a MySQL View, and then just query the view once?

Comment: M... I had to google what MySQL View is, so yeah without knowing it, can't use it. I'll read about views.